# TeeChart VCL TSeriesBandTool band only shows on mouse move over after upgrade from v2013.09

Tags: vcl, teechart

I upgraded from v2013.09.131119 to v2017.23.171221 recently. Since then some of the TSeriesBandTool bands only show when the mouse moves over the band. Only on some charts. Any ideas? Is there a quick fix?

Comment: Please add a [simple example project](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The quickest solution was to delete the series and bands and recreate.